# CMake not finding CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake

I am trying to install ants in Ubuntu 18 which requires a CMake step.

So far I have taken the following steps:

```
apt-get install ants

cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/stnava/ANTs.git

mkdir /opt/ants
cd /opt/ants

cmake -c -g /tmp/ANTS
```

I keep getting the following error:

> CMake Error: The source directory "/tmp/ANTS" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
>   Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apparently have a typo in the path (S should be lower case), try this:

```
cmake -c -g /tmp/ANTs
```